# Small scale contrasting examples of MVC and other code organizing techniques using javascript?

Tags: javascript

I've been teaching myself to code over the last year and I am now interested in how elegant code actually looks. I am very confused regarding this. Personally, I really enjoy how javascript creates classes (function constructors) and derivative objects. Outside of this inherent constraint I don't know what "well organized code" really looks like. So I want to ask if there are any websites that demonstrate various organizational methodologies like MVC using one (very) small simple example program like a cash register that adds tax. The program would be written in a variety of methodologies so the reader can get a "feel" for each one as they compare to the others.

Comment: This is a good question but I'm afraid it might be "Not Constructive" for this site. Also (in my opinion), a small example won't do an architectural pattern for client-side code any justice since it's not managing any complexity.

Comment: Well, let me rephrase to "a program that doesn't need to be any larger than it has to be to demonstrate bare minimum organizational concepts". Thanks for letting me know it was a good question even if it doesn't fit in here.